# Text To Speech in Arabic in Ionic 2 app

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I want my application to respond in the Arabic language. I used cordova plugin tts, it works fine for English but does not respond in Arabic. sayText is the function triggered when the button is pushed.

The .tts code :

```
sayText(speech):void {
  try{
     this.tts.speak({
       text: speech,
       locale: "ar-AE"
     }).then(() => console.log("Succesfully spoke" ));

  }
  catch(e){
  console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use **responsivevoice js**  it's supported Arabic speech (Male and Female)

official website : [Click here](https://responsivevoice.org/)

```
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
```

Comment: how can I import this into my ionic 2 application?